# Initializing a store's data in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs-stores

I have **store** that I would like to initialize from a database but I couldn't find a standard init method for the `Ext.data.Store`. I found a couple of examples with the `StoreManager` component, but I think that's not what I'm looking for. I have an MVC structure for my app and I'd like to keep it, I only want to initialize my store's data field using a method I define. Could someone explain how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I either understand you wrong or your question is straight forward. You configure a store with a model like this. That's all. You may just chose a provider(reader/writer) that fit your needs.

```
 // Set up a model to use in our Store
 Ext.define('User', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: [
         {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'lastName',  type: 'string'},
         {name: 'age',       type: 'int'},
         {name: 'eyeColor',  type: 'string'}
     ]
 });

 Ext.define('YourMVCNameSpace.data.UserStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    constructor: function (config) {
         config = Ext.Object.merge({}, config);
         var me = this;
         // do what you need with the given config object (even deletes) before passing it to the parent contructor
         me.callParent([config]);
         // use me forth on cause the config object is now fully applied
     },
     model: 'User',
     proxy: {
         type: 'ajax',
         url: '/users.json',
         reader: {
             type: 'json',
             root: 'users'
         }
     },
     autoLoad: true
 });
```

Note that the reader will expect a Json result like this:

```
{"total": 55, "users":["...modeldata.."]}
```

and is referring to a url like

```
http://localhost/YourAppDomain//users.json
```

Place the store as 'User' within the controller store array and retrieve it within the Controller by calling `getUserStore()` or directly from the Ext.StoreMgr using Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('User');

Note that by convention the Controller (MVC) will override any storeId you set on the store and will just use the name.

Comment: I think I almost get it but could you explain what exactly the config parameter is and why the constructor needs it?

Comment: @Peter That's for cloning the config so that you don't modify the original config object. Stores are no components and are therefore a bit different. It is a good practice but most times you wan't have any problems without even any constructor.